# Elastic Beanstalk / Docker - No such file or directory package.json

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic beanstalk to launch an app using a nodejs container and a mongodb container. I have created my own image for the node web app, and I am able to use this image to create a container both locally, and and on an EC2 instance with no issue. When using Beanstalk to launch the application though, the CMD "npm run prod" is not able to find my package.json file. Here are a few notes about my setup and the issue:

- Using Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker Environment
- Using Dockerrun.aws.json file with two images: Mongo, and custom nodejs web app image hosted on dockerhub
- I can pull the image down and run it with 'Docker run  npm run prod' and it works (locally and on the EC2 instance that EB has created)
- When EB tries to start the image (with the same command) it errors out and says it cannot find package.json (see error below for details).

I'm not sure if I have a misunderstanding about how Elastic Beanstalk works, or if there is something else I am missing.

Dockerrun.aws.json file (Image name and env vars removed):

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "mongo-vol",
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/var/app/mongo-vol"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "web-vol",
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/var/app/web-vol"
        }
    }
],
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "mongo",
        "image": "mongo:3.4",
        "essential": false,
        "memory": 128
    },
    {
        "name": "web",
        "image": "<IMAGE NAME>",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 128,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "hostPort": 80,
                "containerPort": 3000
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            "mongo"
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "sourceVolume": "web-vol",
                "containerPath": "/starter",
                "readOnly": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Dockerfile for node web app:

```
FROM node:6-slim
COPY . /starter
COPY package.json /starter/package.json
WORKDIR /starter
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN yarn install --production
RUN npm install forever -g
CMD npm run prod
EXPOSE 8888
```

npm script from package.json:

```
"prod": "forever app.js",
```

Error log from docker container:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.2
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.43-17.38.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "prod"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /starter/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open  '/starter/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/starter/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /starter/npm-debug.log
```

Error log after changing CMD to bash -c "pwd && ls -alh && npm run prod"

```
/starter
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Sep  1 16:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K Sep  1 16:01 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  885 Sep  1 16:01 npm-debug.log
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.2
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.43-17.38.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "prod"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /starter/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open  '/starter/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/starter/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /starter/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Change CMD to `bash -c "pwd && ls -alh && npm run prod"`. Post the new logs after those changes

Comment: I added the error log to the post. It shows that the file is not present. No files are present at all. If I ssh into the EC2 instance and run Docker run -it <IMAGE ID> bash, and then ls in /starter the files are present. Again, I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding something here, but that is very odd to me.

Comment: If I ssh into the EC2 instance and run sudo docker run <IMAGE> bash -c "pwd && ls -alh && npm run prod" it works, and all the files are present. Very confused

Comment: In my container definition (Dockerrun.aws.json file) I have my mount point defined with a container path of '/starter'... I am wondering if this is overwriting the files path?

Comment: Yes that is your problem. A mount will shadow everything form inside

Comment: I changed the 'containerPath' value, and that solved my issue. I definitely misunderstood how the mount points worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the container definitions, under mountPoints, the containerPath value of '/starter' was over writing the data that was already located in /starter. By changing the value, the app was able to start.

Container definition that was causing the issue:

```
    "mountPoints": [
        {
            "sourceVolume": "web-vol",
            "containerPath": "/starter",
            "readOnly": false
        }
```

Modified Container definition:

```
    "mountPoints": [
        {
            "sourceVolume": "web-vol",
            "containerPath": "/web-data",
            "readOnly": false
        }
```